# GTX660 ubuntu 15.05 second display correct resolution not displayed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, display, resolution

Got a Nvidia GTX660. Tried all driver versions since 6 months without getting the solution to work in 1024x768 60. Now I choosed to use the 346.59-0ubuntu1 driver. It was working with the "nouveau driver" but the nouveau driver causes me intempestiv crashes of the whole system and I got borred... and it was only a workaround. I'm sure this resolution is available on my beamer and its working on windobe 7.

Actually I have following output from xrandr:

```
pg@pipoTower: ~/tmp$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2720 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 298mm
1920x1080      60.0*+
1680x1050      60.0  
1600x900       60.0  
1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
1280x800       59.8  
1280x720       60.0  
1024x768       75.0     60.0  
800x600        75.0     60.3  
640x480        75.0     59.9  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected 800x600+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
800x600        60.3*+
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

and here is my xorg.conf

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "BenQ GL2450H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 660"
    Option         "ModeValidation" "NoMaxPClkCheck"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DVI-D-0: 1024x768_60 +1920+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

1. I tried to add the resolution it doesnt work event with

   ```
   pg@pipoTower: ~/tmp$ cvt 1024 768 60
   # 1024x768 59.92 Hz (CVT 0.79M3) hsync: 47.82 kHz; pclk: 63.50 MHz
   Modeline "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync
   pg@pipoTower: ~/tmp$ xrandr --newmode "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync
   pg@pipoTower: ~/tmp$ xrandr --addmode DVI-D-0 1024x768_60.00
   X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
   Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
   Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
   Serial number of failed request:  41
   Current serial number in output stream:  42
   ```

   seems that the ID is invalid according to the /var/log/Xorg.0.log file

   ```
   [ 19156.309] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): The EDID read for display device DFP-3 is invalid:
   [ 19156.309] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): - The EDID has an unrecognized version.
   [ 19156.309] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): - The EDID has a bad checksum. The "IgnoreEDIDChecksum" X
   [ 19156.309] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     configuration option may be used to attempt using mode
   [ 19156.309] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     timings in this EDID in spite of this error. A corrupt
   [ 19156.309] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     EDID may have mode timings beyond the capabilities of your
   [ 19156.309] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     display, and could damage your hardware. Please use with
   [ 19156.309] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     care.
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Raw EDID bytes:
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00  15 2b 03 10 01 01 01 01
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   34 0d 01 03 80 00 00 fe  8a 37 dd a0 55 4f 87 23
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   13 47 4f 2f cf 80 31 59  45 59 61 59 81 59 81 80
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   71 4f 01 01 01 01 64 19  00 40 41 00 26 30 18 88
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   36 00 00 00 00 00 00 18  00 00 00 fd 00 38 55 1f
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   53 0e 00 0a 20 20 20 20  20 20 00 00 00 fc 00 45
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   49 50 2d 32 35 2d 44 49  47 49 54 0a 00 00 00 ff
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 45 30 33 5a 31 35 38  35 0a 20 20 20 20 00 2e
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   [ 19156.309] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
   ```

Answer (score 1):

So, finally, the answer was following.

1. Discovered that the driver could not get the EDID from my beamer as into /var/log/Xorg.0.log file
2. I got it from windows 7 application [Phoenix EDID Designer](http://www.tucows.com/preview/329441/Phoenix-EDID-Designer) which can be run with wine, exported on a raw format in a file put into /etc/X11/myBeamerEDID.raw
3. added it into my xorg.conf into the device section

   ```
   Section "Device"
       Identifier     "Device0"
       Driver         "nvidia"
       VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
       BoardName      "GeForce GTX 660"
       Option         "CustomEDID" "DFP-3:/etc/X11/eiki_eip-25_edid.raw"
   EndSection
   ```
4. Restarted my display manager

   ```
   sudo service sddm restart
   ```